# Why are my Spotify requests so high using Spotipy?

Tags: python, list, spotify, spotipy

I have a script that takes an artist, finds related artists, and then adds their top tracks to a list. Next the script iterates through the list to find songs under a popularity threshold. If the songs are under the threshold then they will be added to a new playlist.

I run into request limits every day after running the script a few times. I am starting to think I have a logical error that I can not find.

My code is below

```
import os
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy.util as util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from datetime import date

cid = ""
secret = ""

os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID'] = cid
os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET'] = secret
os.environ['SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI'] = 'http://example.com'

username = ""

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

scope = 'user-top-read'

auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope) # new
spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager) # new




class Spotify_Analysis:
    def __init__(self):
        self.track_ids = []
        self.artist_ids = []
        self.sortedsongs = []
        self.newartists = []
        self.cleaned_up = []

    def get_related_artists(self):
        artist_name = 'Jim Croce'
        print('Starting search for ' + artist_name)

        result = sp.search(q='artist:' + artist_name, type='artist')
        name = result['artists']['items'][0]['name']
        uri = result['artists']['items'][0]['uri']
        related = sp.artist_related_artists(uri)
        for artist in related['artists']:
            self.artist_ids.append(artist['uri'])


    def even_more_artists(self):

        for uri in self.artist_ids:
            related = sp.artist_related_artists(uri)
            for artist in related['artists']:
                self.newartists.append(artist['uri'])
        print('Found ' + str((len(self.newartists))) + ' similar artists')

    def get_artist_top_tracks(self):
        print('Looking for Artists Songs')
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials())
        count = 0
        for artist in self.newartists:
            response = sp.artist_top_tracks(artist)
            for track in response['tracks']:
                self.track_ids.append(track['id'])
                count += 1
                print('Found ' + str(count) + ' songs')
        print('Found ' + str(len(self.newartists)) + ' Similar Artists')
        print('Found ' + str(len(self.track_ids)) + ' Songs from Similar Artists Before Threshold')

    def create_playlist(self):
        playlist_name = 'Songs You Can Scientifically Say You May Not Know Them (Jim Croce)'
        print('Creating playlist named ' + str(playlist_name))
        scope = "playlist-modify-public"
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope))
        user_id = sp.me()['id']
        playlist = sp.user_playlist_create(user_id, name=playlist_name)
        self.playlist_id = playlist["id"]
        print('Playlist Created')

    def cut_tracks(self):
        print("Beginning to Narrow Down Tracks")
        count = 0
        self.track_ids = [*set(self.track_ids)]
        for track in self.track_ids:
            count = count + 1
            print('Examining song #' + str(count) + ' out of ' + str(len(self.track_ids)))
            if sp.track(track)['popularity'] < 20:
                self.sortedsongs.append(track)

        print('Songs under popularity threshhold: ' + str(len(self.sortedsongs)))

    def add_to_playlist(self):

        print("Adding Tracks to Playlist")
        playlist = self.playlist_id

        while self.sortedsongs:
            sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id=playlist, items=self.sortedsongs[:100],
                                  position=None)
            self.sortedsongs = self.sortedsongs[100:]

        print('Added tracks to playlist')

    def finished(self):
        print('Playlist Compiled')


def main():
    r1 = Spotify_Analysis()
    r1.get_related_artists()
    r1.even_more_artists()
    r1.get_artist_top_tracks()
    r1.create_playlist()
    r1.cut_tracks()
    r1.add_to_playlist()
    r1.finished()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I apologize if my code is not great I am not proficient yet

Comment: You should keep track of exactly how many requests you're sending, and how often. There's no sleeps or delays of any kind in your code so it could be that it's just hammering the API too quickly. IDK. Without having any actual numbers though on what the number of requests you're sending is, or on what the rate limit is, the amount of help I (and probably others) can give is rather limited.

Comment: You can use sp.tracks() instead of sp.track() to get all (max 50 ids) popularity info of an artist's top tracks at ones.